# Notes missing in list transactions

Tags: transactions, square, square-connect

Square connect v2 documentation shows that transaction notes are included in list transaction response but is missing in actual response.

Comment: Please provide more feedback, e.g. by giving us a short code sample

Answer (score 0):

If this is the note field in the Square Point of Sale Android/iOS app on the numeric keypad screen where a charge amount is entered, the note is on the [order line item](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-orderlineitem%E2%80%8C).

We have not added the note field to the `OrderLineItem` object, but have it on our roadmap.

An option is to use the Connect V1 endpoint, which includes line item notes in the [payment endpoints](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#navsection-payments).

Answer (score 0):

Square connect v2 documentation ListTransactions specify that there should be an optional note field as:

```
"note": "some optional note",
```

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions

Square Web API (iOS) specify that we can send note field as:

```
"notes": "Rental fee",
```

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-ios

Using web API to create transaction does not record this note along with the transaction (as we expect).